# Dropdown should not allow the user to enter other words from keyboard which are not present in string array - android

Tags: java, android

I have gave the string-array in Strings.xml

```
<string-array name="WorkTypes">
    <item>Installation</item>
    <item>Maintenance</item>
    <item>AMC</item>
    <item>Training</item>
    <item>Demo</item>
    <item>General</item>
    <item>Leave</item>
    <item>Week-Off</item>
</string-array>
```

and get this string-array in the fragment.

```
WorkTypes = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.WorkTypes)));

CustomAutoCompleteTextView actvEntryCategory;

EntryTypeAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.autocomplete_text_layout, WorkTypes);

actvEntryCategory.setAdapter(EntryTypeAdapter);
```

When User enter `I` from the keyboard, It displays all the strings that are having `I`. when user enter other strings which are not in String-array, It will accept them also.

But I wanted to display error message when user enter strings which are not in String array in Strings.xml

How can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why are you not using spinner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
 public class AutocompleteViewss extends AppCompatActivity {

AutoCompleteTextView autocompleteViewss;

ArrayList<String> WorkTypes;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

String selecteditems = "";

TextInputEditText  editText_addwork;

TextInputLayout cat_types;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_autocomplete_textview);


    autocompleteViewss = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.category_auto);

    editText_addwork  = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.addwork);

    cat_types   = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.cat_types);


    WorkTypes = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.WorkTypes)));

    Toast.makeText(AutocompleteViewss.this,""+WorkTypes.size(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, WorkTypes);

    autocompleteViewss.setAdapter(adapter);



    autocompleteViewss.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            selecteditems = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Log.d("displaythe",""+selecteditems);

            editText_addwork.setEnabled(true);
            cat_types.setError("");


        }
    });


    editText_addwork.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("seleceditems","***    "+selecteditems);

            if (selecteditems.equals("")){
                cat_types.setError("Please Select Types");

                Toast.makeText(AutocompleteViewss.this,"Please Select Work Types",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                cat_types.setError("");

                Toast.makeText(AutocompleteViewss.this,"Show Dialog here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                /* Show dialog here */

           }

        }
    });

}
```

}

**Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="app.msupply.com.chennai_interview.AutocompleteViewss">


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/cat_types"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/category_auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Types">
        </AutoCompleteTextView>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/cat_station"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Station"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>





     </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/cat_ProductName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Product Name"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>



    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>




    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/cat_addwork"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Add Work"
            android:id="@+id/addwork"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:drawableTint="#000"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Screen:**

[image]

Comment: Your answer might helpful to me. please try to help me so that I will change it according to my requirement. @Gowthaman M

Comment: I am new to android and My name is pavani. my requirement is I have an auto complete textview, string array is set to this. So, the user select one from the string array. there is one cardview, when user click on cardview, dialog need to be opened. For example user select `Installation` from text view, when user click on card view `installation dialog` have to open, if user select `maintanance`, when user click on cardview, `maintanance dialog` have to be opened.@Gowthaman M

Comment: @vishnu hi,,You want to create `CardView` Dynamically or how you want.

Comment: @vishnu For example user select Installation from text view then you have to create `CardView` Dynamically i am right.

Comment: No sir, cardview is always there. but when click on cardview dialog has to open depend on the textview selection @Gowthaman M

Comment: @vishnu post some reference images to better understading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162492/discussion-between-vishnu-and-gowthaman-m).